# Performance cost: No loop fusion across function barriers

Tags: julia

For style and performance considerations, I found myself comparing the following two functions. Is it possible to get equivalent performance between the following two ways to add 1 to every element in an array?

```
function inplaceadd1!(ar)
    ar .= ar .+ 1.
end

function add1(ar)
    return(ar .+ 1.)
end

function inplace!(ar)
    ar .= add1(ar)
end

ar1 = rand(10000)
ar2 = ar1[:]

@time inplaceadd1!(ar2)
#0.000010 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
@time inplace!(ar1)
#0.000026 seconds (6 allocations: 78.359 KiB)
```

Not knowing too much about compiler optimizations, to me it seems that `add1` could be inlined into `inplace!` and the loop could be fused to achieve identical performance without extra allocations. Does this not occur?

Appreciate the insight and any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

It does not occur in your case. `add1` normally returns a new array and the compiler is not able to figure out the new array is not necessary at all. Note that `!` is used for style purposes and does not mean anything special to the compiler at the moment.

You should instead write your function element-wise and let the [loop fusion](https://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots) do its work. This is a more Julia way if you are defining element-wise operations.

```
function inplaceadd1!(ar)
    ar .= ar .+ 1.
end

function add1(a)
    a + 1. # no `.+` here
end

function inplace!(ar)
    ar .= add1.(ar)
end
```

Since it is a small function, it should automatically get inlined by the compiler. You can also give a hint to the compiler by using `@inline` macro (annotate your function with `@inline`.)

```
@btime inplaceadd1!($ar2)
# 1.198 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
@btime inplace!($ar1)
# 1.155 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Ah, smart. Thanks, just what I was looking for.